# How to locate an offset and a length of concrete Protobuf message inside encoded byte array?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Given the following Protobuf schema:

```
message Node {
   oneof Kind {
      A a = 101;
      B b = 102;
   }
}

message A {
   Node child = 1;
   string data = 2;
}

message B {
   Node child = 2;
   string data = 3;
}
```

And a byte array representing Protobuf encoded 'Node'.

Is it possible to find an offset and a length inside the encoded byte array, of a nested node whose type is `A` and it has "test" value in its `data` field?

I've seen there's "calculateSize" method that can return a node length, but I have no idea of how to calculate the offset.

Comment: there is no single pre-defined offset; you'd need to parse the fields in order. Not only can `A` optionally have a `child` node, but that allows us to have *any number* of nested nodes, all before we'll ever see the `data` - plus the variable nested payload sizes *themselves* change the layout (sine the length-prefix is varint-encoded). Basically: just deserialize it, or use a protobuf reader API